# MVC4, C# Declare variable values for once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Im using MVC4, C#.

I have two hidden fields in my Index view. GetData is my another view in which I have implemented infinite scroll, displays data using hidden fields in Index. Whenever the scrollbar is at bottom it reloads the GetData controller, for second time the values in GetData controller are null. Could someone tell me how do I execute a block of code only for once.

Im passing hiddenfields values in Index View

```
  @Html.BeginForm("GetData", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
  @Html.Hidden("Input1")
  @Html.Hidden("Input2")
```

GetData Controller

```
public ActionResult GetData(int? id, string Input1, string Input2)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            lat = Convert.ToDecimal(Input1);
            lng = Convert.ToDecimal(Input2);
            count++;
        }
        decimal I1 = Input1;
        decimal I2 = Input2;
     }
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from your action. Is there some code you aren't showing us?

Comment: yes. Ive posted only the issue im facing here

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repost to the same action wouldn't it be better to load the new data when you hit the bottom of the scroll using an AJAX request. You could then keep hold of the input values on the client and submit them (to a new action) with the AJAX request.

Comment: Ive created a class which has a GetData method which returns the list every time I scroll to bottom. Could you tell me how do I pass hiddenfield values to this class?

Comment: The hiddenfields in Index view holds some values, passing these Im doing some computational steps and return GetData view. As Im passing values from Index on button click, whenever I reached bottom, Getdata controller hits again and the parameter values are set to null. Is there a way I can store the hidden fields values other than DB?